# Fake an attack like a bully does

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Sometimes after a fight when both parties have settled down, one of them will feint an attack trying to make the other flinch. I'm looking for word or phrase (a verb) that could describe that as succinctly as possible.

> When he walked past Owen, he *lurched* (or _______) at him. Owen stood his ground staring defiantly at the tattooed man.

The word “lurch" doesn't convey the element of deceit I am looking for.

I am willing to accept other parts of speech (e.g., nouns like “stratagem” or “trickery”)

Comment: What's wrong with using the word *feint*? A single word with a definite meaning seems succinct.

Comment: The verb "feint" is usually intransitive.

Comment: The verb 'posture' is a hypernym.

Comment: Welcome! I see that you are a new contributor. Please edit your question to include two things so that it can be reopened. First, please include a couple possible sentences illustrating how you would use this term, leaving a blank `________` where it would go. Second, please **present your research** into this by showing us which possible terms you discovered but discarded, and tell us why you found each of those inappropriate for your purposes.

Comment: I added an explanation as to why "lurch" was unsatisfactory, feel free to rollback the edit or to change the reason.

Comment: I have made, and documented, the assumption that you are looking specifically for a verb. If you are willing to accept other parts of speech (e.g., nouns like “stratagem” or “trickery”), please [edit] your question to say so.

Answer (score 1):

You've already used the most idiomatic word: it's a **feint**:

> deceive by a mock action
>
> > Near the brush fence two roosters bowed and **feinted** at each other with squared wings and neck feathers ruffed out.
>
> [*The Pearl* vocab at Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/lists/352298)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single word but you are allowing a phrase.

*When he walked past Owen, he made as if to attack him.*

*When he walked past Owen, he faked a lunge at him.*

*When he walked past Owen, he gave a fake lunge at him.*

*When he walked past Owen, he made a mock lunge at him.*

*When he walked past Owen, he threw a dummy (punch) at him.*

---

Boxing: Feint: Faking or feinting a punch is used to make an opponent unnecessarily react, or to gauge his response so that it throws him off his game or makes him commit to a false move. https://www.titleboxing.com/boxing-dictionary

Comment: I think "feigned an attack" would be idiomatic, as well.

Comment: @user888379 - Yes. I hadn't thought of that one.